# Joomla custom SSO plugin

Tags: joomla-3.x, plugin, joomla-api, single-sign-on

I need to create a custom SSO plugin. The way it should work is:

1. User authenticates on 3rd party application
2. 3rd party application calls a Joomla URL via POST request
3. The URL that has been hit deals with authentication on Joomla's end
4. User is logged in both on Joomla and on 3rd party application

I know how to create a custom plugin for authentication as I've done it in the past, but I can't find a way to expose a plugin URL for point 2. Is there a way to expose a plugin URL, or is there any other way to achieve the above? Users will register and login on the 3rd party application, but I still need them authenticated on the Joomla website. Thank you.

**UPDATE**

I have tried to implement the procedure outlined below, including the plugin from a component, but it's not working.

/components/com_testauth/controllers/sso.php

```
class TestAuthControllerSso extends JControllerLegacy
{
 public function auth() {
    JPluginHelper::importPlugin('user');
    JPluginHelper::importPlugin('authentication');
    $dispatcher = JEventDispatcher::getInstance();
    $options = '';
    $response = new \stdClass();
    $credentials = array();
    $credentials["username"] = "test";
    $credentials["password"] = "tset";
    $results = $dispatcher->trigger('onUserAuthenticate', array($credentials, 
     $options, &$response));

    return $results;
}

}
```

/plugins/authentication/test/test.php (This has been copied from Joomla documentation to test the functionality)

```
class PlgAuthenticationTest extends JPlugin
{
   function onUserAuthenticate( $credentials, $options, &$response )
    {
        
        /*
         * Here you would do whatever you need for an authentication routine with the credentials
         *
         * In this example the mixed variable $return would be set to false
         * if the authentication routine fails or an integer userid of the authenticated
         * user if the routine passes
         */
        $db = JFactory::getDbo();
    $query  = $db->getQuery(true)
        ->select('id')
        ->from('#__users')
        ->where('username=' . $db->quote($credentials['username']));

    $db->setQuery($query);
    $result = $db->loadResult();
    

    if (!$result) {
        $response->status = STATUS_FAILURE;
        $response->error_message = 'User does not exist';
    }

    /**
     * To authenticate, the username must exist in the database, and the password should be equal
     * to the reverse of the username (so user joeblow would have password wolbeoj)
     */
    if($result && ($credentials['username'] == strrev( $credentials['password'] )))
    {
        $email = JUser::getInstance($result); // Bring this in line with the rest of the system
        
        $response->email = $email->email;
        
        $response->status = JAuthentication::STATUS_SUCCESS;
        
        return true;
        
    }
    else
    {
        $response->status = JAuthentication::STATUS_FAILURE;
        $response->error_message = 'Invalid username and password';
    }
    }
    
    
}
```

The problem is that I can log in ok if I log in through the log in form, but I can't log in if I call the component controller from the URL. The credentials of the user are hard-coded to avoid mistakes, so that the authentication should always be correct.

The process I followed is:

1. Created a component that includes the authentication plugin.
   a. Please note that I'm including the whole "authentication" plugin, including
   the single plugin doesn't seem to work.
2. Created an authentication plugin
3. Visited the controller URL - index.php?option=com_testauth&task=sso.auth

**UPDATE 2**

I have come up with another solution, which unfortunately it's not working at 100%, but it may help people in the future.

What I did is:

1. Created an Ajax plugin, and installed it as an Ajax plugin in Joomla to expose the URL, code as follows:

`

```
function onAjaxSSO()
{
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$input = $app->input;
$app->setHeader('X-Robots-Tag', 'noindex, nofollow');   
$task = $input->get("task", "", "cmd"); 
$app->logout(JFactory::getUser()->id, array()); 

//Do all the security checks to see if the call is legit or not and if it has all the right details.
[...]

//Pass the details to the authentication plugin
$loginResponse = $app->login(array('username' => $username, 'email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'name' => $forename.' '.$surname), array('silent' => true));    

//Check what is the response from the authentication plugin and display the message on the API response

if($loginResponse === true) {
    $app->setHeader('status', 200, true);
    $result = "";
    echo new JResponseJson($result, 'Success - User is authenticated', false);
    return $app->close();
}
else {
    $app->setHeader('status', 401, true);
    $result = '';
    echo new JResponseJson($result, 'Unauthorized - User is not authenticated', true);
    return $app->close();
}
}
```

`

2. Created an authentication plugin, this deals with all the authentication stuff. Code as follows, parts are missing for brevity:

`

```
function onUserAuthenticate( $credentials, $options, &$response )
{

$app = JFactory::getApplication();
        
//No log in for admins
if ($app->isClient('administrator')) {

    $response->status        = JAuthentication::STATUS_FAILURE;
    return false;
}

//We check Joomla database to see if the details are the same
[...]

//Authenticate the user if everything looks legit

    $user                    = JUser::getInstance($joomlaId);
    $response->email         = $user->email;
    $response->fullname      = $user->name;
    $response->username      = $user->username;
    $response->language      = $user->getParam('language');
    $response->status        = JAuthentication::STATUS_SUCCESS;
    $response->error_message = '';

}
```

`

When I call the API exposed with the Ajax plugin, I get a "true" response from the plugin, the authentication goes fine (I can see the user being updated/inserted on the database), and I can also see, from the back-end, the user in the list of "Active users", but nothing changes on the front-end. The user is not properly logged-in, the joomla_user_state cookie has not been created and everything seems like the user has never logged in. If I try to print

`echo JFactory::getUser()->id`

I get 0.

Comment: Welcome to JSE.  Please take our [tour].  Please continue to attempt to resolve you issue while you wait for support/feedback.  If you manage to resolve your own issue, please post an educational answer to your question.

Comment: I achieved this by authenticating a WordPress user in Joomla (same domain; two sites - one Joomla, one Wordpress) by creating a simple Joomla component, which is easily exposed via URL. In the component, I used a `task` and some parameters to call the authentication plugin. The params were non-descript but essentially used to check in the authentication plugin if the user was currently logged in on the WordPress site. All the auth plugin has to do is return true/false. Might be worth thinking about - at the time (circa 5 years ago) - there was no other method I found which would do this.

Comment: Thank you, @GrantG. So you are saying that I can achieve this by triggering the `onUserAuthenticate` event of a custom authentication plugin? Is this achieved by using JPluginHelper as below?

`JPluginHelper::importPlugin('mycustomauth');
$dispatcher = JEventDispatcher::getInstance();
$dispatcher->trigger('onUserAuthenticate', $data);`

Comment: Yes, that is correct. You would use your `mycustomauth` plugin to handle `$data` and return true/false to authenticate the user.

Comment: Thank you very much, @GrantG. I'll wait and see if someone else knows another way of achieving this but, if not, I will add the information on my question.

Comment: @GrantG, I have tried to implement this but it's not working. I have updated my question, can you please have a look? Thanks.

Comment: @Kabal this could be falling down for a number of reasons. There are a multitude of scenarios you may need to go down, which is probably too broad a discussion for a comment board like this; but to begin, have you confirmed your component controller is calling the sso auth()?

Comment: @GrantG: I have updated the question again, trying another solution. Still failing, but I was able to go a bit further. 
To answer your question, the component controller was calling the sso auth() correctly, but it wasn't registering the "true" or "false" response from the authentication plugin.

Comment: @Kabal so your $results remains empty? Have you confirmed that is still the case with returning false in your `else {STATUS_FAILURE}`?

Comment: @GrantG, So sorry, but what is the `$results` variable? The `$loginResponse` response variable gets populated correctly. If the code on the authentication plugin returns true, the `$loginResponse` is equal to true. If the code on the authentication plugin returns false, then is equal to false. I don't understand why the user is not logged in in the front-end of the website, the session_id is populated in the database, and I can see the users from the back-end. The "last visited date" gets updated too, but `JFactory::getUser()` remains empty.

Answer (score -3):

Affiliation Disclosure: I have direct direct affiliation with the below mentioned product/company, so readers should be aware of inherent bias in my recommendation.

Customization depends on which features you want while performing SSO like role mapping or attribute mapping as well as user provisioning. You can use the miniOrange Joomla SAML SP plugin. [Click here to see the solution](https://plugins.miniorange.com/joomla-single-sign-sso-using-google-apps-idp).

With Identity provider as Google apps and to authenticate users from Google apps to login to Joomla site which is acts as service provider.

While performing SSO, it maps attributes like profile and groups too.

Comment: Not only have you posted two spammy answers, but you have worded them with the intent to deceive since you say "In my site". It would have been far more genuine if you would have come clean about your affiliation to the company/product.  It has been brought to my attention that you have been suspended on other sites for spam posts.  Perhaps no one has explained your foul.  Please discontinue posting further spam anywhere in the Stack Exchange Network.